# How can I pass a variable to an inner thread class?

Tags: java, image

I want to load an image at periodic intervals to an imageitem. My outer class is generating the URL and I need to pass it to the innerclass. How do I achieve this?

```
public class MapTimer extends TimerTask{
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Map starting...");

        String URL=null,serverquery=null;
        try {
            sendMessage(this.message);
            item.setLabel(item.getLabel()+"start");
            serverquery=receiveMessage();
            item.setLabel(item.getLabel()+"stop");
            URL = getURL(serverquery);               // my url to be passed to innerclass
            System.out.println("URl is "+serverquery);
            item.setLabel(URL+item.getLabel());
            Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                    item.setLabel(item.getLabel()+"6");
                    try {
                          Image image = loadImage(URL);            // using url
                          System.out.println("GEtting image....");
                          item = new ImageItem(null, image, 0, null);
                          form.append(item);
                          display.setCurrent(form);

                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                          item.setLabel("Error1");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ioe) {
                          item.setLabel("Error1");
                    }
              }
         };
         t.start(); // write post-action user code here
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Error3"+e);
     }
  }    
}
```

How do I pass the URL to my innerthread class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to declare the variable final or don't use a variable but a field in the class.

```
public class YourClass {

private String url;

public void yourMethod {
   url = getURL(serverquery);
   System.out.println("URl is "+serverquery);
   item.setLabel(URL+item.getLabel());
   Thread t = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
         item.setLabel(item.getLabel()+"6");
         try {
           Image image = loadImage(url);            // using url
           System.out.println("GEtting image....");
           item = new ImageItem(null, image, 0, null);
           form.append(item);
           display.setCurrent(form);

    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      item.setLabel("Error1");
    }
                catch (Exception ioe) {
      item.setLabel("Error1");
    }

  }
};
t.start(); // write post-action user code here
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It should work if your URL is contained in a final reference. This means that the reference won't move. Consequently, you can't initialize it to null and then call getURL, you need to declare it at this point:

```
final String URL = getURL(serverquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that there are (at least) 2 major ways of doing this on whever your thread gets the information or recieves the information (in your case URL)

1) gets the informations:

what you want to do is keep a reference of the object containing the data you need (like URL) in your Thread, and when your ready the Thread gets the next item/URL to load.

```
public class MapTimer extends TimerTask{
   public void run() {
     ...
   }
   private URLGenerator urlGenerator = null;
   public MapTimer(URLGenerator urlGen){
      ...
   }
```

This will give you the option to get the next URL when your thread is free (with a if(urlGen != null) of course)

2) Receives Information

Works better for cases where the thread is called only when the rest of the program wants to (user inputing data etc)

```
public class MapTimer extends TimerTask{
       public void run() {
         ...
       }
       private URL urlToLoad = null;
       public void setURL(URL urlToLoad){
          ...
          //store and wake up thread
       }
```

this way your thread recieve with a setter the data it needs to run, processes it then waits for the next data to be send to it (of course you need to be careful of thread issues like multiple calls etc.)

Hope this helps you

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Just make the field a static variable belonging to the class and not any object instance of the class, like this:

```
public YourClass {

    private static String url;

    //...
}
```

Please note however that the static variable will be shared among all object instances of the class.